# Implicit Conversion from Any to Dynamic

Tags: scala, dynamic-typing

Why isn't the following working? (Yes, I am working with *2.9.0final* and turned the "*-Xexperimental*" option on.)

```
implicit def any2Dynamic(a: Any) = new Dynamic {
  def applyDynamic(name: String)(args: Any*) = {
    println(a + name)
  }
}

"Say".hello // value hello is not a member of java.lang.String
```

One can argue about how meaningful this is... If this would work as expected what precedence will take place at `"Say".toInt`: `StringLike.toInt` or `(new Dynamic {...}).applyDynamic("toInt")`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler first [looks](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.9.0.RC3/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Typers.scala#L3533) for an implicit view from `String => { def hello: ? }`. That fails, so it then [checks](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.9.0.RC3/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Typers.scala#L3546) if `String <: Dynamic`. These are not combined.

This dynamic apply feature has not been finalized -- in Scala 2.9.0 it is experimental, and subject to change. But I doubt this would be included, as with such an implicit, you throw all type safety out the window. You would never get a compile error for misspelled method names or incorrect argument types. What is your use case?

Comment: Your right with type safety. But what if I restrict the implicit def to my use case `implicit def X2Dynamic(x: X) = new X {...}` (my problem remains, type safety problem restricted to `X`) to build a DSL with dynamic invocation, so one can invoke methods that e.g. defined externally in xml. Just an experiment in mind so far... By the way, thanks for links to source!

Comment: I actually think this sort of behavior is great. It can allow using dynamic language capabilities in a narrow scope. Great for scripts or DSL.

Comment: @IttayD Me, too ;) At least to have it in mind when it comes to a sophisticated answer to a decent question here on SO.